# Add columns Query With parameters

Tags: sql-server-2008, alter-table

Hello all I'm having 1 Question with following query syntax

```
 ALTER TABLE table_name
 ADD column_name column-definition;
```

Question is can we use parameters to `column_name` field like `@column_name`? Because I'm creating columns which Column name is supplied by front end as a parameter. for example

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD @column_name varchar(250);
```

this is giving error so any alternate for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps try:

```
DECLARE @sql varchar(max);
SET @sql = 'ALTER TABLE table_name ADD ' + @column_name + ' varchar(250);';
EXEC (@sql);
```

Comment: To be on the safe side from malicious or ignorant end-users  you should use [quotename()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx). `quotename(@column_name)`

Comment: Another good option.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson what are the advantages  of using quotename(@column_name) over @column_name?

Comment: @M.S.Nayak - It will remove (I belive) the risk of [SQL-injection](http://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL-injektion) and it will allow your column names to contain otherwise invalid characters like `space`. For more info you can have a look here: [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)

Comment: @MikaelEriksson Thanks I got it referred  http://www.blackhat.com/presentations/bh-usa-06/BH-US-06-Neerumalla.pdf